# Is there a way of realigning the world along with scene understanding on Hololens 2?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

Im working on an application for use with the HoloLens 2 that allows the user to make real world measurements and save them localy. As a base for Scene Understanding I made use of the demo code Microsoft provides. The app works fine but whenever I load in an existing save file the world and the measurements are misaligned.

The HoloLens gets a new 0 point whenever you start the headset, which will never be exactly the same. Scene Understanding automatically aligns itself back to the correct position and rotation, but my measurements do not.

Is there a way of aligning my gameobjects along with Scene Understanding?

Comment: What version of Unity are you using? Have you tried the spatial anchor?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/spatial-anchors-in-unity?tabs=anchorstore

Comment: I'm using Unity 2020.3.28f1. And I have indeed tried spatial anchors set to be persistant. But my gameobjects are still misaligned. All it seems to do is stop the Scene Understanding objects from moving. So with spatial Anchors enabled my measurements are now in the "correct" place in the room, but the whole room is misaligned.

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve] so we can understand your issue better?